# Re-fill a textbox's text if left blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a login form that clears text from the field after a user clicks on it. How can I have the field's value be replaced with the original text if the field looses focus and is empty? Something like

```
$("#input_field").loseFocus(//Total pseudocode. 
    if((this).attr("value")==''){
        (this).attr("value","Original text! Woohoo!");
    }
);
```

I do use jQuery, and I can provide the webpage if it's necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#input_field").blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() ==''){
        $(this).val(this.defaultValue);
    }
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/gVPHM/1/

Comment: You could get the original test from the attribute `$(this).attr('value')`

Comment: ah, .blur(). Learn something new every day. Thanks.

Comment: @Adam, that won't work - but you did remind me of defaultValue

Comment: As it so happens, I'm writing a login form. The password field is naturally all bullets, and "Password" and "Username" have the same number of characters. So, for this instance, I'm just filling both fields with "Username."

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html) instead? It would be far more appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Use focusout http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

```
$("#input_field").focusout(

  if($(this).val().length == 0){
    $(this).attr("value","Original text! Woohoo!");
  }

)
```

or to do whitespaces as well.

```
$("#input_field").focusout(

  if(jQuery.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
    $(this).attr("value","Original text! Woohoo!");
  }

)
```

Comment: -1 focusout makes no sense in this example. The purpose of focusout is to use propagation so it will fire if any child of the selector loses focus. An input field won't have any children, so `blur` is the most appropriate event in this case. Also, blur is roughly twice as fast as focusout: http://jsperf.com/blur-vs-focusout

Answer (score -2):

Something like:

```
var originalValue = '';
$("#field").click(function(){
   originalValue = 'Original value';
});

$("#field").loseFocus(function(){
   if(valueNeedsToBeRestored()){
      $("#field").attr('value',originalValue);
});
```

**EDIT:
Downvoters, please explain why you downvoted so i can learn. Thank you.**